# ngx-translate with Angular universal has problems translating parameterised value

Tags: javascript, angular, server-side-rendering, angular-universal, ngx-translate

I'm working on migrating my Angular 10 application to SSR using Angular universal and I'm facing issues with ngx-translate while translating parameterised values.

I have a translation

```
Bei Kauf von {quantity}
```

where this quantity is an attribute from our component and we normally translate it like
`{{ 'LABEL' | translate: {quantity: 1} }}` and we will see **Bei Kauf von 1**

But with SSR it's not at all translating. I see `Bei Kauf von {quantity}` on the page. I checked many forums and I don't see potential solutions. Any help would be much appreciated.

Here is my **translate-server.loader.ts**

```js
    import { join } from 'path';
    import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
    import { TranslateLoader } from '@ngx-translate/core';
    import {
      makeStateKey,
      StateKey,
      TransferState
    } from '@angular/platform-browser';
    import * as fs from 'fs';
    
    export class TranslateServerLoader implements TranslateLoader {
      constructor(
        private transferState: TransferState,
        private prefix: string = 'i18n',
        private suffix: string = '.json'
      ) {}
    
      public getTranslation(lang: string): Observable<any> {
        return new Observable((observer) => {
          const assets_folder = join(
            process.cwd(),
            'dist',
            'my-app',
            'browser',
            'assets',
            this.prefix
          );
    
          const jsonData = JSON.parse(
            fs.readFileSync(`${assets_folder}/${lang}${this.suffix}`, 'utf8')
          );
    
          // Here we save the translations in the transfer-state
          const key: StateKey<number> = makeStateKey<number>(
            `transfer-translate-${lang}`
          );
          this.transferState.set(key, jsonData);
    
          observer.next(jsonData);
          observer.complete();
        });
      }
    }
    
    export function translateServerLoaderFactory(transferState: TransferState) {
      return new TranslateServerLoader(transferState);
    }
```

translate-browser.loader.ts

```js
    import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
    import { TranslateLoader } from '@ngx-translate/core';
    
    import {
      makeStateKey,
      StateKey,
      TransferState
    } from '@angular/platform-browser';
    import { TranslateHttpLoader } from '@ngx-translate/http-loader';
    import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
    
    export class TranslateBrowserLoader implements TranslateLoader {
      constructor(private http: HttpClient, private transferState: TransferState) {}
    
      public getTranslation(lang: string): Observable<any> {
        const key: StateKey<number> = makeStateKey<number>(
          `transfer-translate-${lang}`
        );
        const data = this.transferState.get(key, null);
    
        // First we are looking for the translations in transfer-state,
        // if none found, http load as fallback
        if (data) {
          return new Observable((observer) => {
            observer.next(data);
            observer.complete();
          });
        } else {
          return new TranslateHttpLoader(this.http).getTranslation(lang);
        }
      }
    }
    
    export function translateBrowserLoaderFactory(
      httpClient: HttpClient,
      transferState: TransferState
    ) {
      return new TranslateBrowserLoader(httpClient, transferState);
    }
```

app.server.module.ts

```js
    import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
    import { ServerModule, ServerTransferStateModule } from '@angular/platform-server';
    import { FlexLayoutServerModule } from '@angular/flex-layout/server';
    import { TranslateModule, TranslateLoader } from '@ngx-translate/core';
    import { translateServerLoaderFactory } from './shared/loaders/translate-server.loader';
    import { TransferState } from '@angular/platform-browser';
    
    import { AppModule } from './app.module';
    import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
    import { EnvironmentService } from '~shared/services/environment.service';
    
    @NgModule({
      imports: [
        AppModule,
        ServerModule,
        ServerTransferStateModule,
        TranslateModule.forRoot({
          loader: {
            provide: TranslateLoader,
            useFactory: translateServerLoaderFactory,
            deps: [TransferState]
          }
        }),
        FlexLayoutServerModule,
      ],
      providers: [EnvironmentService],
      bootstrap: [AppComponent],
    })
    export class AppServerModule {}
```

app.module.ts

```js
    imports: [
    ....,
        TranslateModule.forRoot({
          loader: {
            provide: TranslateLoader,
            useFactory: translateBrowserLoaderFactory,
            deps: [HttpClient, TransferState]
          }
        }),
    ]
```

**Note: It's working fine for all others which don't have any parameterised values in translations**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be double curly brackets

```
Bei Kauf von {{quantity}}
```

Comment: Thanks buddy. U saved my life. One more question. What should we do if we have this
Bei Kauf von {{quantity}} {quantity, plural, =1{} =2{} =3{} =4{} =5{+} other{+}}. I mean I need to show if more than 5 items Bei Kauf von 5+. Any idea??

Comment: Sorry, I don't get it (:

Comment: I mean how to use pluralization with Angular universal?

Comment: Sorry, I can not help here. Haven't touched universal for ages (: And even haven't made the pluralization with ngx-translate so far

Answer (score 0):

wanna notice 2 more things, idk if it changed in last versions of Angular, but don't forget to register TransferState in app.module providers

```
 providers: [
    TransferState,
    ...
]
```

and for translate-server.loader.ts if you have some type errors for node.js use

```
/// <reference types="node" /> // add this line
import {join} from 'path';
```

at the top.
If it doesn't help, try to add

```
"types" : ["node", "express"],
```

to your tsconfig.json inside "compilerOptions"
It took me some time))